# Run queries after page load

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Sorry if this is not the proper place to post Oracle Apex questions. But I'll post anyway maybe someone could help.

I have an application with a dashboard as the homepage. The dashboard is full of Interactive Reports, Cards, Charts, etc. So basically it has more then 10 SQL queries.

My issue is it takes time to load the page because of the queries. So I'm looking for a way to defer the running of the queries and only try to auto run them after page load or once the DOM is ready and not stuck on the login page with the loading animation.

What are some possible ways to handle this issue?

Comment: Which version do you use? In 5.0 and higher, it is already implemented there by default.

Answer (score 1):

For the IR/classic regions, you can use this lazy loading technique from Maxime

http://max-tremblay.blogspot.com/2018/05/lazy-loading-report.html

5.1+ OracleJET charts populate after page load already.

Alternatively, you could consider materialized views on your data

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/materialized-views